# The swap and assignment operator calls themselves in linked list class, causing stack overflow

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack-overflow, dynamic-arrays

I'm getting this error from Visual Studio when trying to print the ArrayList's items:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF9E8AF8739 (ucrtbased.dll) in List.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000007E50C13FF8).
```

I have no idea what to make of this. I was trying to implement copy-and-swap idiom.

I was reading a file of numbers, add its digits to a linked list. And appending that linked list to a dynamic array and print its content. Both LinkedList and ArrayList have their `operator<<` overloaded.

LinkedList.hpp:

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_HPP
#define LINKEDLIST_HPP

#include "List.hpp"
#include "Node.hpp"

#include <iostream> // operator<<

template <typename T>
class LinkedList: public List<T>
{
private:
    Node<T>* m_head{nullptr};
    Node<T>* m_tail{nullptr};

    int m_size{};

    void swap(T& a, T& b)
    {
        auto temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }

    void swap(LinkedList<T>& a, LinkedList<T>& b)
    {
        LinkedList<T> temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }

public:
    LinkedList() = default;

    LinkedList(std::initializer_list<T> i_list)
    {
        for (const auto& item : i_list)
        {
            append(item);
        }
    }

    // Copy constructor.
    LinkedList(const LinkedList<T>& other) : List<T>{}
    {
        auto temp = other.m_head;

        while (temp != nullptr)
        {
            append(temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    ~LinkedList()
    {
        // Start from the beginning.
        Node<T>* temp = m_head;

        // Traverse the list while deleting previous elements.
        while (temp != nullptr)
        {
            temp = temp->next; // Move forward.
            delete m_head;     // Delete the previous element.
            m_head = temp;     // m_head moved one forward.
        }
    }

    // Assignment operator using copy-and-swap idiom.
    LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList<T>& other)
    {
        if (&other != this)
        {
            LinkedList<T> temp(other);

            /*Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF9DEC58739 (ucrtbased.dll) in List.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000009A1D6F3FE8).*/
            swap(*this, temp);
        }

        return *this;
    }

    auto head() const
    {
        return m_head;
    }

    auto tail() const
    {
        return m_tail;
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        return m_size == 0;
    }

    int size() const
    {
        return m_size;
    }

    void prepend(const T& item)
    {
        // Create a node holding our item and pointing to the head.
        auto new_item = new Node<T>{item, m_head};

        // If the head is the last element
        // (meaning it is the only element),
        // it'll be the tail.
        if (m_head == nullptr)
        {
            m_tail = m_head;
        }

        m_head = new_item;
        m_size++;
    }

    void append(const T& item)
    {
        // Create a node with no pointer.
        auto new_item = new Node<T>{item};

        if (m_tail == nullptr)
        {
            // If the list is empty, set the new item as the head as well.
            m_head = new_item;
            m_tail = new_item;
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise, update the current tail's next pointer to the new item and move the tail.
            m_tail->next = new_item;
            m_tail = new_item;
        }

        m_size++;
    }

    // Avoid illegal indexes by making pos unsigned.
    void insert(const unsigned pos, const T& item)
    {
        // If the position is the beginning of the list, prepend the new node.
        if (pos == 0)
        {
            prepend(item);
        }
        // If the position is beyond the end of the list, append the new node.
        else if (static_cast<int>(pos) >= m_size)
        {
            append(item);
        }
        else
        {
            // Create a new node.
            auto new_item = new Node<T>{item};

            // Starting from the head, go to the one past the position.
            auto temp = m_head;
            for (int i{}; i < static_cast<int>(pos) - 1; ++i)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
            }

            new_item->next = temp->next; // Link the new_item to the one after the temp.
            temp->next = new_item;       // Link temp to the new_item.

            m_size++;
        }
    }

    void remove_front()
    {
        Node<T>* temp = m_head;

        // If there's no element, exit.
        if (m_head == nullptr)
        {
            return;
        }

        m_head = m_head->next; // Move m_head one element forward.
        delete temp;           // Get rid of the previous element.

        m_size--;
    }

    void remove_back()
    {
        Node<T>* temp = m_head;

        if (temp == nullptr)
        {
            return;
        }

        // If the list's size is 1.
        if (temp == m_tail)
        {
            delete temp;
            m_head = m_tail = nullptr;

            --m_size;

            return;
        }

        // Traverse to one before the end.
        while (temp->next != m_tail)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        m_tail = temp;
        //temp = temp->next;
        delete temp->next;

        m_tail->next = nullptr;

        --m_size;
    }

    // Avoid illegal indexes by making pos unsigned.
    T remove(const unsigned pos)
    {
        Node<T>* temp = m_head;

        // Go to the one past the pos.
        for (int i{}; i < static_cast<int>(pos) - 1; ++i)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        // The element to be removed.
        auto to_removed = temp->next;
        // Link the current node one after the to_removed.
        temp->next = temp->next->next;

        T removed_data = to_removed->data; // Retrieve the data before deleting the node.

        delete to_removed; // Delete the to_removed.
        m_size--;          // Don't forget to decrement the size.

        return removed_data;
    }

    T& operator[](const int pos)
    {
        Node<T>* temp = m_head;

        for (int i{}; i != pos; ++i)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        return temp->data;
    }

    const T& operator[](const int pos) const
    {
        Node<T>* temp = m_head;

        for (int i{}; i != pos; ++i)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        return temp->data;
    }
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const LinkedList<T>& list)
{
    for (auto begin = list.head(); begin != nullptr; begin = begin->next)
    {
        os << begin->data << ' ';
    }
    return os;
}

#endif // LINKEDLIST_HPP
```

ArrayList.hpp:

```
// An array-based approach of list.
#ifndef ARRAYLIST_HPP
#define ARRAYLIST_HPP

#include "List.hpp"
#include <cassert>

const int GROWTH_FACTOR = 2;

template <typename T>
class ArrayList: public List<T>
{
private:
    int m_capacity{};     // Maximum size of list.
    int m_size{};         // Current number of list elements.
    T*  m_list_array{};   // Array holding list of elements.

    void reserve()
    {
        m_capacity *= GROWTH_FACTOR;
        T* temp = new T[m_capacity];   // Allocate new array in the heap.

        for (int i{}; i < m_size; ++i)
        {
            temp[i] = m_list_array[i]; // Copy all items of original array.
        }
        
        delete[] m_list_array;         // Get rid of the original array.
        m_list_array = temp;           // "temp" is our new array now.
    }

public:
    ArrayList() = default;

    ArrayList(int size)
        : m_capacity{size*GROWTH_FACTOR},
        m_size{size},
        m_list_array{new T[m_capacity] {}} // ArrayList elements are zero initialized by default.
    {
    }

    ArrayList(std::initializer_list<T> i_list)
        : ArrayList(static_cast<int>(i_list.size())) 
        // Don't use braces as initializer_list constructor uses it.
        // Otherwise this constructor would call itself.
    {
        int count{};
        for (const auto& item : i_list)
        {
            m_list_array[count] = item;
            count++;
        }
    }

    // Copy constructor.
    /*
     * Rule of Three:
     * If a class requires a user-defined destructor, 
     * a user-defined copy constructor, 
     * or a user-defined copy assignment operator, 
     * it almost certainly requires all three.
     */
    ArrayList(const ArrayList& other)
        : List<T>{},
        m_capacity{other.m_capacity},
        m_size{other.m_size},
        m_list_array{new T[other.m_capacity] {}}
    {
        for (int i{}; i < m_size; ++i)
        {
            m_list_array[i] = other.m_list_array[i];
        }
    }

    ~ArrayList()
    {
        delete[] m_list_array;
    }

    ArrayList& operator=(const ArrayList& other)
    {
        // Check for self-assignment.
        if (this != &other)
        {
            // Deallocate the existing array.
            delete[] m_list_array;

            // Copy the capacity and size.
            m_capacity = other.m_capacity;
            m_size = other.m_size;

            // Allocate a new array.
            m_list_array = new T[m_capacity];

            // Copy the elements from the other ArrayList.
            for (int i{}; i < m_size; ++i)
            {
                m_list_array[i] = other.m_list_array[i];
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }

    // initializer_list assignment.
    ArrayList& operator=(std::initializer_list<T> i_list)
    {
        // Array's new size is the i_list's size now.
        m_size = static_cast<int>(i_list.size());

        // reserve(), but without copying items because they'll been assigned from i_list.
        if (m_capacity < m_size)
        {
            m_capacity *= GROWTH_FACTOR;
            T* temp = new T[m_capacity] {};   // Allocate new array in the heap, with zero values.

            delete[] m_list_array;            // Get rid of the original array.
            m_list_array = temp;              // "temp" is our new array now.
        }

        // Copy the i_list's items to our array's.
        int count{};
        for (const auto& item : i_list)
        {
            m_list_array[count] = item;
            count++;
        }

        return *this;
    }


    void clear()
    {
        delete[] m_list_array;              // Remove the array.
        //m_size = 0;                         // Reset the size.

        m_list_array = new T[m_capacity] {}; // Recreate array.
    }

    // Insert "item" at given position.
    void insert(const unsigned pos, const T& item)// override
    {
        if (m_size == m_capacity)
        {
            reserve();
        }
        assert(static_cast<int>(pos) < m_size && "Out of range.\n");

        for (int s{m_size}; static_cast<int>(pos) < s; --s)        // Shift elements up...
        {
            m_list_array[s] = m_list_array[s - 1]; // ...to make room.
        }
        ///DEMONSTRATION
        //┌────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┐
        //│i[0]│i[1]│i[2]│i[3]│i[4]│i[5]│i[6]│     // INDEXES
        //├────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
        //│10  │20  │30  │40  │50  │60  │    │     // ITEMS
        //├────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
        //│    │10  │20  │30  │40  │50  │60  │     // SHIFT ELEMENTS UP
        //├────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
        //│item│10  │20  │30  │40  │50  │60  │     // INSERT "item"
        //└────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┘
        //
        m_list_array[pos] = item;

        m_size++;                                  // Increment list size.
    }

    // Append "item".
    void append(const T& item) override
    {
        if (m_size == m_capacity)
        {
            reserve();
        }
        //assert(m_size < m_capacity && "List capacity exceeded.\n");

        m_list_array[m_size] = item;
        m_size++;
    }

    // Remove and return the current element.
    T remove(const unsigned pos) override
    {
        assert(static_cast<int>(pos) < m_size && "No element.\n");

        T item = m_list_array[pos];                // Copy the item.

        // m_size - 1, because we're dealing with array indexes (array[size] is out of bounds).
        for (int i{static_cast<int>(pos)}; i < m_size - 1; ++i)
        {
            m_list_array[i] = m_list_array[i + 1]; // Shift elements down.
        }
        ///DEMONSTRATION
        //┌────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┐
        //│i[0]│i[1]│i[2]│i[3]│i[4]│i[5]│i[6]│     // INDEXES
        //├────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
        //│10  │item│20  │30  │40  │50  │60  │     // ITEMS
        //├────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
        //│10  │20  │30  │40  │50  │60  │... │     // SHIFT ELEMENTS DOWN
        //└────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┘
        //
        m_size--;                                  // Decrement size.

        return item;
    }

    // Return list size.
    int size() const override
    {
        return m_size;
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        return size() == 0;
    }

    T& operator[](const int pos) override
    {
        assert(!empty() && "No current element.\n");
        return m_list_array[pos];
    }

    const T& operator[](const int pos) const override
    {
        assert(!empty() && "No current element.\n");
        return m_list_array[pos];
    }
};
#endif // ARRAYLIST_HPP
```

List.hpp:

```
// This is a blueprint for all list-like data structures.
// It won't specify how the operations are carried out.
#ifndef LIST_HPP
#define LIST_HPP

#include <initializer_list>

template <typename T>
class List
{
public:
    List()
    {}

    virtual ~List()
    {}

    List(const List&)
    {}

    virtual void insert(unsigned pos, const T& item) = 0;
    virtual void append(const T& item) = 0;

    virtual T remove(const unsigned pos) = 0;

    virtual int size() const = 0;

    virtual T& operator[](const int pos) = 0;
    // The const overload is called only when used on const object.
    virtual const T& operator[](const int pos) const = 0;

};
#endif // LIST_HPP
```

Node.hpp:

```
#ifndef NODE_HPP
#define NODE_HPP

template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    T data{};            // Value of the node.
    Node* next{nullptr}; // Pointer to the next node.

    Node(const T& dat, Node* nxt = nullptr)
        : data{dat}, next{nxt}
    {}
};

#endif // NODE_HPP
```

Source.cpp:

```
#include "LinkedList.hpp"
#include "ArrayList.hpp"

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define TO_DIGIT(x) (x) - ('0')

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const List<T>& list)
{
    for (int i{}, s{list.size()}; i < s; ++i)
    {
        os << list[i] << ' ';
    }
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream fin("number.txt");

    if (!fin.good())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    std::string num{};
    ArrayList<LinkedList<int>> arr{};

    while (fin >> num)
    {
        LinkedList<int> list{};
        for (const char& ch : num)
        {
            list.prepend(TO_DIGIT(ch));
        }

        arr.append(list);
    }

    std::cout << arr;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically it seems like a lot more code than a [mre].

Comment: Use a debugger, look for a deep recursion in your code.

Comment: In general graph-like containers (linked lists, queues, trees, graphs, etc) should not be implented as composers because coypying and destruction stack cost is linear. And stack is a most limiting factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed several bugs in your code. Namely:

- Removed those `swap` functions out of LinkedList.  And then fixed your LinkedList overloaded assigment operator to do a proper copy instead of some swap thing.

Instead of this:

```
    // Assignment operator using copy-and-swap idiom.
    LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList<T>& other)
    {
        if (&other != this)
        {
            LinkedList<T> temp(other);
            swap(*this, temp);
        }

        return *this;
    }
```

This:

```
    LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList<T>& other)
    {
        if (&other != this)
        {
            while (m_size > 0) {
                remove_back();
            }

            auto other_head = other.m_head;
            while (other_head != nullptr) {
                append(other_head->data);
                other_head = other_head->next;
            }
        }

        return *this;
    }
```

- Several places in LinkedList where `m_size` gets decremented, but you forget to set m_head and m_tail to nullptr when this happens.  `remove_front` and `remove` specifically.
- The `reserve` method in ArrayList needed a quick fix to handle the case where capacity was initially zero. In which case, the easy fix is to grow the size to 2.
- Removed most of those overloaded copy constructors and assignment operators in ArrayList.  They weren't getting used and I wasn't convinced they were needed. You can add them back, but I wasn't convinced it wasn't a source of a bug.

After all that, your code seems to work.

Here's your code after the above fixes.

```
template <typename T>
class List
{
public:
    List()
    {}

    virtual ~List()
    {}

    List(const List&)
    {}

    virtual void insert(unsigned pos, const T& item) = 0;
    virtual void append(const T& item) = 0;

    virtual T remove(const unsigned pos) = 0;

    virtual int size() const = 0;

    virtual T& operator[](const int pos) = 0;
    // The const overload is called only when used on const object.
    virtual const T& operator[](const int pos) const = 0;

};

template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    T data{};            // Value of the node.
    Node* next{ nullptr }; // Pointer to the next node.

    Node(const T& dat, Node* nxt = nullptr)
        : data{ dat }, next{ nxt }
    {}
};

const int GROWTH_FACTOR = 2;

template <typename T>
class ArrayList : public List<T>
{
private:
    int m_capacity{};     // Maximum size of list.
    int m_size{};         // Current number of list elements.
    T* m_list_array{};   // Array holding list of elements.

    void reserve()
    {
        m_capacity *= GROWTH_FACTOR;
        if (m_capacity == 0) {
            m_capacity = 2;
        }
        T* temp = new T[m_capacity];   // Allocate new array in the heap.

        for (int i{}; i < m_size; ++i)
        {
            temp[i] = m_list_array[i]; // Copy all items of original array.
        }

        delete[] m_list_array;         // Get rid of the original array.
        m_list_array = temp;           // "temp" is our new array now.
    }

public:
    ArrayList() = default;

    ~ArrayList()
    {
        delete[] m_list_array;
    }


    void clear()
    {
        delete[] m_list_array;
        m_list_array = nullptr;
        m_capacity = 0;
        m_size = 0;
    }

    // Insert "item" at given position.
    void insert(const unsigned pos, const T& item)// override
    {
        if (m_size == m_capacity)
        {
            reserve();
        }
        assert(static_cast<int>(pos) < m_size && "Out of range.\n");

        for (int s{ m_size }; static_cast<int>(pos) < s; --s)        // Shift elements up...
        {
            m_list_array[s] = m_list_array[s - 1]; // ...to make room.
        }
        ///DEMONSTRATION
        //┌────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┐
        //│i[0]│i[1]│i[2]│i[3]│i[4]│i[5]│i[6]│     // INDEXES
        //├────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
        //│10  │20  │30  │40  │50  │60  │    │     // ITEMS
        //├────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
        //│    │10  │20  │30  │40  │50  │60  │     // SHIFT ELEMENTS UP
        //├────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
        //│item│10  │20  │30  │40  │50  │60  │     // INSERT "item"
        //└────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┘
        //
        m_list_array[pos] = item;

        m_size++;                                  // Increment list size.
    }

    // Append "item".
    void append(const T& item) override
    {
        if (m_size == m_capacity)
        {
            reserve();
        }
        //assert(m_size < m_capacity && "List capacity exceeded.\n");

        m_list_array[m_size] = item;
        m_size++;
    }

    // Remove and return the current element.
    T remove(const unsigned pos) override
    {
        assert(static_cast<int>(pos) < m_size && "No element.\n");

        T item = m_list_array[pos];                // Copy the item.

        // m_size - 1, because we're dealing with array indexes (array[size] is out of bounds).
        for (int i{ static_cast<int>(pos) }; i < m_size - 1; ++i)
        {
            m_list_array[i] = m_list_array[i + 1]; // Shift elements down.
        }
        ///DEMONSTRATION
        //┌────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┐
        //│i[0]│i[1]│i[2]│i[3]│i[4]│i[5]│i[6]│     // INDEXES
        //├────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
        //│10  │item│20  │30  │40  │50  │60  │     // ITEMS
        //├────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
        //│10  │20  │30  │40  │50  │60  │... │     // SHIFT ELEMENTS DOWN
        //└────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┘
        //
        m_size--;                                  // Decrement size.

        return item;
    }

    // Return list size.
    int size() const override
    {
        return m_size;
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        return size() == 0;
    }

    T& operator[](const int pos) override
    {
        assert(!empty() && "No current element.\n");
        return m_list_array[pos];
    }

    const T& operator[](const int pos) const override
    {
        assert(!empty() && "No current element.\n");
        return m_list_array[pos];
    }
};

template <typename T>
class LinkedList : public List<T>
{
private:
    Node<T>* m_head{ nullptr };
    Node<T>* m_tail{ nullptr };

    int m_size{};


public:
    LinkedList() = default;

    LinkedList(std::initializer_list<T> i_list)
    {
        for (const auto& item : i_list)
        {
            append(item);
        }
    }

    // Copy constructor.
    LinkedList(const LinkedList<T>& other) : List<T>{}
    {
        auto temp = other.m_head;

        while (temp != nullptr)
        {
            append(temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    ~LinkedList()
    {
        // Start from the beginning.
        Node<T>* temp = m_head;

        // Traverse the list while deleting previous elements.
        while (temp != nullptr)
        {
            temp = temp->next; // Move forward.
            delete m_head;     // Delete the previous element.
            m_head = temp;     // m_head moved one forward.
        }
    }

    // Assignment operator using copy-and-swap idiom.
    LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList<T>& other)
    {
        if (&other != this)
        {
            while (m_size > 0) {
                remove_back();
            }

            auto other_head = other.m_head;
            while (other_head != nullptr) {
                append(other_head->data);
                other_head = other_head->next;
            }
        }

        return *this;
    }

    auto head() const
    {
        return m_head;
    }

    auto tail() const
    {
        return m_tail;
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        return m_size == 0;
    }

    int size() const
    {
        return m_size;
    }

    void prepend(const T& item)
    {
        // Create a node holding our item and pointing to the head.
        auto new_item = new Node<T>{ item, m_head };

        // If the head is the last element
        // (meaning it is the only element),
        // it'll be the tail.
        if (m_head == nullptr)
        {
            m_tail = m_head;
        }

        m_head = new_item;
        m_size++;
    }

    void append(const T& item)
    {
        // Create a node with no pointer.
        auto new_item = new Node<T>{ item };

        if (m_tail == nullptr)
        {
            // If the list is empty, set the new item as the head as well.
            m_head = new_item;
            m_tail = new_item;
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise, update the current tail's next pointer to the new item and move the tail.
            m_tail->next = new_item;
            m_tail = new_item;
        }

        m_size++;
    }

    // Avoid illegal indexes by making pos unsigned.
    void insert(const unsigned pos, const T& item)
    {
        // If the position is the beginning of the list, prepend the new node.
        if (pos == 0)
        {
            prepend(item);
        }
        // If the position is beyond the end of the list, append the new node.
        else if (static_cast<int>(pos) >= m_size)
        {
            append(item);
        }
        else
        {
            // Create a new node.
            auto new_item = new Node<T>{ item };

            // Starting from the head, go to the one past the position.
            auto temp = m_head;
            for (int i{}; i < static_cast<int>(pos) - 1; ++i)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
            }

            new_item->next = temp->next; // Link the new_item to the one after the temp.
            temp->next = new_item;       // Link temp to the new_item.

            m_size++;
        }
    }

    void remove_front()
    {
        Node<T>* temp = m_head;

        // If there's no element, exit.
        if (m_head == nullptr)
        {
            return;
        }

        m_head = m_head->next; // Move m_head one element forward.
        delete temp;           // Get rid of the previous element.

        m_size--;

        if (m_size == 0) {
            m_head = nullptr;
            m_tail = nullptr;
        }
    }

    void remove_back()
    {
        Node<T>* temp = m_head;

        if (temp == nullptr)
        {
            return;
        }

        // If the list's size is 1.
        if (temp == m_tail)
        {
            delete temp;
            m_head = m_tail = nullptr;

            --m_size;

            return;
        }

        // Traverse to one before the end.
        while (temp->next != m_tail)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        m_tail = temp;
        //temp = temp->next;
        delete temp->next;

        m_tail->next = nullptr;

        --m_size;
    }

    // Avoid illegal indexes by making pos unsigned.
    T remove(const unsigned pos)
    {
        Node<T>* temp = m_head;

        // Go to the one past the pos.
        for (int i{}; i < static_cast<int>(pos) - 1; ++i)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        // The element to be removed.
        auto to_removed = temp->next;
        // Link the current node one after the to_removed.
        temp->next = temp->next->next;

        T removed_data = to_removed->data; // Retrieve the data before deleting the node.

        delete to_removed; // Delete the to_removed.
        m_size--;          // Don't forget to decrement the size.

        if (m_size == 0) {
            m_head = nullptr;
            m_tail = nullptr;
        }

        return removed_data;
    }

    T& operator[](const int pos)
    {
        Node<T>* temp = m_head;

        for (int i{}; i != pos; ++i)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        return temp->data;
    }

    const T& operator[](const int pos) const
    {
        Node<T>* temp = m_head;

        for (int i{}; i != pos; ++i)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        return temp->data;
    }
};
```

Comment: May I also ask you another question? Is it a bad thing that most position parameters are "const"? I was reading about const correctness and thought that would be good practice.

Comment: You typically want to pass references to big objects by `const &` (const reference) whenever you can. That enables a few optimizations and parameter coercion. (e.g. you can pass a `"string literal"` into a function expecting `const std::string&` and avoid a lot of overhead).  But for plain old value types like `unsigned int`, `char`, `float`, etc... passing as const value (e.g. `foo(const int x)` ) just helps eliminate accidental bugs in large functions where you change the value of the parameter in one place but another part of the function expects it to be the original value.

Comment: The concept of "pass all your simple value parameters as const" pattern is something that has been recently evangelized by some well known C++ enthusiasts as good code hygiene in the last few years.  I don't think this evangelized pattern revolutionizes programming in any significant way. It just helps to avoid bugs and makes for more readable code.  Now that I've recently been programming in Kotlin where all function parameters are implicitly "val" (equivalent to const), I kind of appreciate this concept. But when I review C++ code, I really don't enforce this ideal.

Comment: @selbie how that even can protect from bugs?  THe only thing it does that on some platforms that it gets rid of certain dependencies between CPU instructions at risk of using more stack space (can't use the argument as local variable, which is rarely done anyway).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm getting this error from Visual Studio:
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF9E8AF8739 (ucrtbased.dll) in List.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000007E50C13FF8).
>
> I have no idea what to make of this. I was trying to implement copy-and-swap idiom.

The swap function needs to be rewritten. It should swap the *members* of your `LinkedList` class, not the `LinkedList` objects themselves.

As things stand, your swap function invokes the assignment operator, which in turn, calls swap, which calls the assignment operator, and so on. You have an infinite recursion.

```cpp
    void swap(LinkedList<T>& a, LinkedList<T>& b)
    {
        // ERROR - Infinite recursion
        LinkedList<T> temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }
```

In addition, you should code your swap functions as `noexcept`, and use move operations to effect the swaps.

There are several other errors in your program. The [answer by @selbie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77414676/22193627) does a good job explaining the details.

##### No need for inheritance

A deeper problem is the overall design. Using inheritance to create class `ArrayList` is way more complicated than you need. Think about how you would code this if you were using `std::vector` and `std::forward_list`, rather than custom classes. There would be no inheritance. Instead, you would create a vector of lists:

```cpp
std::vector<std::forward_list<int>> arr;
```

Your custom classes should be *composable* in the same way.

##### Code function `main` using `std::vector` and `std::forward_list`

One approach to this problem is to code a solution using `std::vector` and `std::forward_list`. When you have that working, you can replace them with classes of your own design.

In the following code snippet, the macro `USE_STD` allows you to choose between Standard Library classes and custom replacements.

- When `USE_STD == 1`, the program uses `std::vector` and `std::forward_list`.
- When `USE_STD == 0`, the program uses `tbx::cpp23::Vector` and `tbx::cpp23::Forward_List`.

```cpp
// main.ixx
module;
#define USE_STD 0
export module main;
import std;

#if USE_STD
    template< typename T >
    using Forward_List = std::forward_list<T>;

    template< typename T >
    using Vector = std::vector<T>;
#else
    import tbx.cpp23.Forward_List;
    import tbx.cpp23.Vector;

    template< typename T >
    using Forward_List = tbx::cpp23::Forward_List<T>;

    template< typename T >
    using Vector = tbx::cpp23::Vector<T>;
#endif

// ...
```

From this point forward, use the type aliases: `Vector` and `Forward_List`. This defintion, for example, is taken from function `main`:

```cpp
Vector<Forward_List<int>> arr;
```

##### Stream insertion operators

The macro `USE_STD` can also be used to select which versions of `operator<<` to use.

```cpp
#if USE_STD
    std::ostream& operator<< (
        std::ostream& ost,
        Forward_List<int> const list)
    {
        for (auto const& item : list)
            ost << item << ' ';
        ost << '\n';
        return ost;
    }
#else
    // The implementation of `tbx::cpp23::Forward_List<T>` defines 
    // `operator<<` as a hidden friend. No definition is needed here.
#endif

std::ostream& operator<< (
    std::ostream& ost,
    Vector<Forward_List<int>> const vec)
{
    for (auto const& list : vec)
        ost << list;
    ost.put('\n');
    return ost;
}
```

##### Source code for function `main`

This is the source code for function `main`. Because it uses the type aliases `Forward_List` and `Vector`, it works with both Standard Library class, and their custom replacements.

```cpp
export int main()
{
    enum : int { no_errors, create_error, open_error, skipped_number };
    int exit_code = no_errors;

    // numbers.txt
    // This is the input file.
    std::string file_name_numbers{ "number.txt" };

    // skipped.txt
    // Invalid "numbers" are written to this file.
    std::string file_name_skipped_numbers{ "skipped.txt" };

    if (!create_file_numbers(file_name_numbers, 3))
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR - Could not create file: \""
            + file_name_numbers + '"';
        return create_error;
    }

    std::ifstream ist(file_name_numbers);
    if (!ist.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR - Could not open file: \""
            + file_name_numbers + '"';
        return open_error;
    }

    std::ofstream log(file_name_skipped_numbers);
    if (!log.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR - Could not open file: \""
            + file_name_skipped_numbers + '"';
        return open_error;
    }

    Vector<Forward_List<int>> arr;

    std::string num{};
    while (ist >> num)
    {
        if (is_digit_string(num))
        {
            // Note: This loop duplicates the action of the OP.
            // It reverses the order of the digits. Thus, the MSD
            // is pushed onto the front of the list first, followed 
            // by the other digits. It would be easy to parse string 
            // `num` in reverse order, and thereby create a list with 
            // the digits in their original order.
            Forward_List<int> list;
            for (const char& ch : num)
                list.push_front(digit_to_int(ch));
            arr.push_back(list);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr
                << "ERROR - Skipping invalid number in input file: "
                << num
                << '\n';
            log << num << '\n';
            exit_code = skipped_number;
        }
    }
    ist.close();
    log.close();
    std::cout << arr;
    return exit_code;
}
```

##### Helper functions

Function `main` calls these helper functions:

```cpp
bool create_file_numbers(
    std::string const& file_name,
    int n = 5)
{
    // This file is not described in the OP at StackOverflow.
    // Judging by how it is used, the file is comprised of a series 
    // of non-negative integer values (without any sign, + or -), 
    // separated by whitespace. 
    // 
    // For convenience, let's suppose there is one number per line.

    std::ofstream ost{ file_name };
    if (!ost.is_open())
        return false;
    std::mt19937 mt{ std::random_device{}() };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist{ 0, 99'999 };
    while (n--)
        ost << dist(mt) << '\n';
    ost.close();
    return true;
}

int digit_to_int(char const c) {
    return c - '0';
}

bool is_digit_string(std::string_view sv) noexcept
{
    for (char const& c : sv)
        if (!std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char const>(c)))
            return false;
    return !sv.empty();
}
```

##### Tips for coding custom classes

The custom classes `Forward_List` and `Vector` should both follow the [Rule of Five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Other than that, you can simplify your task by coding only the member functions you use. There is no need to implement the complete interface of `std::forward_list` and `std::vector`.

- Function `main` invokes `push_front` on the list, and `push_back` on the vector. No other member functions are used.
- For the vector, `operator<<` uses a *range-based for loop*. To make that work, you must code member functions `cbegin` and `cend`. In my implementation, they simply return pointers, rather than full-blown iterators.
- For the list, `operator<<` also required implementing member functions `cbegin` and `cend`.
- The list also has a supplemental `Node` class, which is used internally, but is not exposed to clients.
- For the list, I wrote an iterator class. Internally, the iterator class stores a pointer to a `Node`. When you increment an iterator, the pointer gets incremented. However, when you dereference an iterator, it does not return a `Node`; it returns a reference to the `value` field from struct `Node`.

I coded my demonstration program using `import` and modules, but the same solution can be coded with regular `#include` directives.

Module `tbx.cpp23.Forward_List` defines class template `tbx::cpp23::Forward_List<T>`.

```cpp
// Forward_List.ixx
export module tbx.cpp23.Forward_List;
export namespace tbx::cpp23
{
    template< typename T >
    class Forward_List
    {
    public:
        using value_type = T;

    private:
        struct Node
        {
            value_type value{};
            Node* next{ nullptr };
            bool operator== (Node const& that) const {
                return this->value == that.value;
            }
        };

        Node *head{}, *tail{};

    public:
        struct Iterator
        {
            // ...
        };
        // ...
    };
}
```

Module `tbx.cpp23.Vector` defines class template `tbx::cpp23::Vector<T>`.

```cpp
// Vector.ixx
export module tbx.cpp23.Vector;
export namespace tbx::cpp23
{
    template< typename T >
    class Vector
    {
    public:
        using value_type = T;
        using size_type = std::size_t;
        using iterator = value_type*;
        using const_iterator = value_type const*;

    private:
        size_type capacity_{};
        size_type size_{};
        value_type* data_{ nullptr };
        enum : size_type { zero, one, two };

    public:
        // ...
    };
}
```

##### Demonstration program

Here is the complete source code for file `main.ixx`. Source code for modules `Forward_List` and `Vector` has been omitted. Had to leave some of the fun for you!

At first, I tested with `USE_STD` set to `1`. Later, I tested with it set to `0`. The demo worked both ways.

```cpp
// main.ixx
module;
#define USE_STD 0
export module main;
import std;

#if USE_STD
    template< typename T >
    using Forward_List = std::forward_list<T>;

    template< typename T >
    using Vector = std::vector<T>;
#else
    import tbx.cpp23.Forward_List;
    import tbx.cpp23.Vector;

    template< typename T >
    using Forward_List = tbx::cpp23::Forward_List<T>;

    template< typename T >
    using Vector = tbx::cpp23::Vector<T>;
#endif

#if USE_STD
    std::ostream& operator<< (
        std::ostream& ost,
        Forward_List<int> const list)
    {
        for (auto const& item : list)
            ost << item << ' ';
        ost << '\n';
        return ost;
    }
#else
    // The implementation of `tbx::cpp23::Forward_List<T>` defines 
    // `operator<<` as a hidden friend. No definition is needed here.
#endif

std::ostream& operator<< (
    std::ostream& ost,
    Vector<Forward_List<int>> const vec)
{
    for (auto const& list : vec)
        ost << list;
    ost.put('\n');
    return ost;
}

bool create_file_numbers(
    std::string const& file_name,
    int n = 5)
{
    // This file is not described in the OP at StackOverflow.
    // Judging by how it is used, the file is comprised of a series 
    // of non-negative integer values (without any sign, + or -), 
    // separated by whitespace. 
    // 
    // For convenience, let's suppose there is one number per line.

    std::ofstream ost{ file_name };
    if (!ost.is_open())
        return false;
    std::mt19937 mt{ std::random_device{}() };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist{ 0, 99'999 };
    while (n--)
        ost << dist(mt) << '\n';
    ost.close();
    return true;
}

int digit_to_int(char const c) {
    return c - '0';
}

bool is_digit_string(std::string_view sv) noexcept
{
    for (char const& c : sv)
        if (!std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char const>(c)))
            return false;
    return !sv.empty();
}

export int main()
{
    enum : int { no_errors, create_error, open_error, skipped_number };
    int exit_code = no_errors;

    // numbers.txt
    // This is the input file.
    std::string file_name_numbers{ "number.txt" };

    // skipped.txt
    // Invalid "numbers" are written to this file.
    std::string file_name_skipped_numbers{ "skipped.txt" };

    if (!create_file_numbers(file_name_numbers, 3))
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR - Could not create file: \""
            + file_name_numbers + '"';
        return create_error;
    }

    std::ifstream ist(file_name_numbers);
    if (!ist.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR - Could not open file: \""
            + file_name_numbers + '"';
        return open_error;
    }

    std::ofstream log(file_name_skipped_numbers);
    if (!log.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR - Could not open file: \""
            + file_name_skipped_numbers + '"';
        return open_error;
    }

    Vector<Forward_List<int>> arr;

    std::string num{};
    while (ist >> num)
    {
        if (is_digit_string(num))
        {
            // Note: This loop duplicates the action of the OP.
            // It reverses the order of the digits. Thus, the MSD
            // is pushed onto the front of the list first, followed 
            // by the other digits. It would be easy to parse string 
            // `num` in reverse order, and thereby create a list with 
            // the digits in their original order.
            Forward_List<int> list;
            for (const char& ch : num)
                list.push_front(digit_to_int(ch));
            arr.push_back(list);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr
                << "ERROR - Skipping invalid number in input file: "
                << num
                << '\n';
            log << num << '\n';
            exit_code = skipped_number;
        }
    }
    ist.close();
    log.close();
    std::cout << arr;
    return exit_code;
}
// end file: main.ixx
```